# copy a small dataframe inside another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I would like to update a dataframe with a second dataframe. I have a solution with .loc and .iloc but it is slow and need several operations. I think a better solution exists:

My fist dataframe is :

Df1:

```
Index|item 1|Item n|item n+1|item n+2|Item m
A|a|aa|aaa|aaaa|aaaaaaa
B|b|bb|bbb|bbbb|bbbbbb
C|c|cc|ccc|cccc|cccccccc
D|d|dd|ddd|dddd|ddddddd
```

My df2:

```
Index|item x|item y
102|az|ez
256|fafa|foo
12|fifi|fufu
50|fofo|fefe
```

The goal is to copy in all the `df2` in `df1` (with a `rotation`):

`ez` goes to `[items n, A]` `(replace aa)`

`az` goes to `[items n, B]` `(replace bb)`

`foo` goes to `[items n+1, A]` `(replace aaa)`

`fafa` goes to `[items n+1, B]` `(replace bb)`

I hope I am clear.

Comment: can you edit your question with the expected output, and maybe your current solution

Comment: does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.rot90 function

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.txt',sep='|')
df1.set_index('Index',inplace=True)
df1
item 1  Item n  item n+1    item n+2    Item m
Index                   
A   a   aa  aaa aaaa    aaaaaaa
B   b   bb  bbb bbbb    bbbbbb
C   c   cc  ccc cccc    cccccccc
D   d   dd  ddd dddd    ddddddd


df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.txt',sep='|')

df1.columns 
df2
Index   item x  item y
0   102 az  ez
1   256 fafa    foo
2   12  fifi    fufu
3   50  fofo    fefe


rotate = df2.loc[0:1,'item x':'item y'].values
import numpy as np
df1.loc['A':'B','Item n':'item n+1'] =  np.rot90(rotate, k=3, axes=(1,0))
df1
item 1  Item n  item n+1    item n+2    Item m
Index                   
A   a   ez  foo aaaa    aaaaaaa
B   b   az  fafa    bbbb    bbbbbb
C   c   cc  ccc cccc    cccccccc
D   d   dd  ddd dddd    ddddddd
```